# Why can't I use !(single pattern) in zsh even after I turn on kshglob?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

This works in bash:

```
touch a b c
echo !(a)
```

If I execute above script in zsh (with `kshglob` on), it complains:

```
zsh: number expected
```

If I add `|` after `a`, it works:

```
echo !(a|)
```

Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because in this case, it conflicts with [*bare glob qualifiers*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-BARE_005fGLOB_005fQUAL_002c-use-of) since it's at the end of the pattern. `*(a1)` is taken as the files last accessed in the last day. `(a1)` is treated as a glob qualifier. So in your `!(a)` case, zsh complains about the missing number of days after the `a` glob qualifier (here applied to the file called `!`).

In `zsh` globs, `(...)` grouping is mostly used for the `(foo|bar)` alternation, so adding a `|` is a documented way to make sure a trailing `(...)` is not treated as a glob qualifier.

Another documented alternative is to double the parenthesis (`!((a))`) or you could add an empty glob qualifier (like `!(a)(-)`).

To completely remove that ambiguity, one can turn off the `bare_glob_qual` option (`set +o bareglobqual`), after which glob qualifiers have to be written with the `extendedglob` `(#q...)` syntax (`*(#qa1)` here).

The `kshglob` option ([added in 1998](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1998/msg00099.html), roughly the same time `bash` added its `extglob` though bash didn't have any extended glob before that) is mostly there for the `ksh` emulation mode (`emulate ksh`), for `zsh` to be able to run `ksh` scripts, where `kshglob` is enabled and `bareglobqual` is disabled. When it was first introduced, after enabling `kshglob`, you'd need to specify glob qualifiers as `-(...)` to avoid that kind of conflict but that caused too much confusion and conflicted with the `@-(...)` syntax of `ksh93`, the `(#q...)` and `bareglobqual` options were introduced later.

`zsh` users generally prefer zsh's own extended glob (`set -o extendedglob`) operators which are easier to type (for most) and more powerful (than the ksh88 ones enabled with `kshglob` also found in `bash -O extglob`).

For example, `!(foo)` would be written `^foo`. The `!(foo|)bar` equivalent would however be longer like `(^(foo|))bar`.

Other ksh88 -> zsh translations:

- `*(x)` -> `x#`
- `+(x)` -> `x##`
- `@(x|y)` -> `x|y`
- `?(x)` -> `(x|)`

Some ksh93 -> zsh translations:

- `~(i:x)` -> `(#i)x` (case insensitive)
- `~(N)x` -> `x(N)` (nullglob, originated in zsh)
- `{1,5}(x)` -> `x(#c1,5)`
- `@(foo&bar)` -> `foo~^bar` or `^(^foo|^bar)`

Some only found in `zsh`:

- `<1-23>` (range of decimal numbers)
- `pattern~except`
- `pattern(glob-qualifier)` (the killer feature of zsh globs)
- `(pattern/)#` (any level of subdirectories matching the `pattern`; the `**/` simplified version of `(*/)#` was also added to ksh93 and bash recently)
- `***/*` (recursive globbing following symlinks).
- `(#a1)foobar` (approximate matching, allowing some errors, here 1)
- ...