# Multiple conditions for a while loop

Tags: shell-script

I have a variable named `choice`. I want to prompt for inputting a value for `choice` until it is non-empty and equal to either `yes` or `no`.

In other words: While `choice` is empty or different that `yes` and `no` then enter choice.

If I write it in Java it would be piece of cake with:

```java
while (choice.IsEmpty() || (!choice.equals("yes") && !choice.equals("no"))
```

But I cannot find a way to translate it to `shell` without using the content (var between double quotes) syntax:

```bsh
while [ "$choice" != "yes" && "$choice" != "no" ]
```

Obviously it works, but, for my personal knowledge, is there another way to test that the same way as in Java?

Comment: In bash, you can use double square brackets and omit the double quotes.

Comment: I think you want "-a" option to test instead of "&&", which is a command separator

Answer (score 21):

This

```
while [ "$choice" != "yes" && "$choice" != "no" ]
```

does actually not work, because the `&&` breaks the `[` command. Use either of:

```
while [  "$choice" != "yes" ] && [ "$choice" != "no" ]
while [[ "$choice" != "yes"   &&   "$choice" != "no" ]]
```

In Bash and other feature-rich shells, you could also use the regex match:

```
while [[ ! $choice =~ ^(yes|no)$ ]]
```

or the ksh-style extended glob, which may need to be explicitly enabled in at least Bash and Zsh:

```
# shopt -s extglob        # Bash, though not needed within [[ .. ]] 
                          #       in recent versions
# setopt kshglob          # Zsh
while [[ $choice != @(yes|no) ]]
```

Or in Zsh, with Zsh's own extended glob syntax:

```
while [[ $choice != (yes|no) ]]
```

(See e.g. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527708/170373)  for the relations between the different extended globs.)

Comment: Note that `[[...]]` is a kshism (now also supported, though with many divergences by zsh, bash, mksh, yash, busybox ash/mush).

Comment: Note that since 4.1 extglob is automatically enabled inside `[[...]]` in bash.

Comment: Note that `[[ $choice =~ ^(yes|no)$ ]]` would return true for `choice=$'yes\n'` in `zsh` if the `re_match_pcre` option was enabled. With PCREs, you need `\z` instead of `$` to match at the end of the subject (as opposed to either the end of the subject of just before a line delimiter at the end of the subject). So `[[ ! $choice =~ '^(yes|no)\z' ]]`. See also https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2017/msg01708.html

Answer (score 13):

A literal translation of `While (choice.IsEmpty() || (!choice.equals("yes") && !choice.equals("no"))` in POSIX `sh` syntax would look like:

```
while
  [ -z "$choice" ] || {
    ! [ "$choice" = yes ] &&
    ! [ "$choice" = no ]
  }
do
 ...
done
```

For a closer match, you could use `ksh93` which has experimental support for object programming:

```
typeset -T java_string=(
  function IsEmpty
  {
    [[ -z $_ ]]
  }
  function equals
  {
    [[ $_ = "$1" ]]
  }
)
```

To declare a `java_string` type of object with two `IsEmpty` and `equals` methods and then:

```
java_string choice
while
  IFS= read -r 'choice?Enter your choice: ' || exit
  choice.IsEmpty || {
    ! choice.equals yes &&
    ! choice.equals no
  }
do
  print -ru2 "Wrong choice: $choice, try again."
done
```

But the `[ -z "$choice" ]` is redundant since if `$choice` is `yes` or `no`, obviously it's not empty.

```
until
  [ "$choice" = yes ] || [ "$choice" = no ]
do
  ...
done
```

would make more sense.

With the Korn shell (or `zsh -o kshglob` or `bash -O extglob` or `bash4.1+`), you can also do:

```
until
  [[ $choice = @(yes|no) ]]
do
  ...
done
```

Answer (score 12):

> is there another way to test that

You could use the standard `case` construct:

```
case $choice in yes|no) false ;; esac
```

which can be used even in the condition part of a `while`, though the construction may end up a bit confusing:

```
while case $choice in yes|no) false ;; esac; do
```

> the same way as in Java?

No