# Zsh - What is this Cool Thing called you get by pressing Tab after "("

Tags: command-line, zsh

## Short Version

If you press `tab` after the following command you get a filer-menu. **What is the name of it?**

```bash
ls *(
```

## Long Version

I just doing my linux-stuff and by accident I pressed `tab` after `(` and a really cool menu popped up I have never seen before.

Suddenly I could select different filters. For example I could look for only directories by typing in `(/)` and so much more filters which are really useful.

I would love to learn more about it, but I have no Idea what to search the internet for. Any idea what this thing is called?

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you using some zsh extensions? Something installed through oh-my-zsh, for example?

Comment: What you get is (probably) the autocompletion for [Glob Qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). Another example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527708/414186). You can for example, list all socket files by using `ls -l *(=)` or if you want to list all non-socket files you can use: `ls -l *(^=)` (or another example, if you want list socket files whose start with `v` you can use: `ls -l v*(=)`)

Comment: ... on my system, it appears to be implemented as a shell function named `_globquals`, which `type _globquals` tells me `is a shell function from /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Zsh/_globquals`. So far as I can tell, it gets loaded from my `.zshrc` by `compinit`

Comment: @terdon I am using `zsh 5.9 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` without any plug-ins nor `oh-my-zsh`. I am not a fan of plug-ins in general^^

Comment: @terdon, you probably skipped the `zsh-newuser-install` menu upon first invocation of `zsh` and didn't run `compinstall` afterwards.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed, thanks @StéphaneChazelas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
```

To your `~/.zshrc` in addition to the styles you already have, it will tell you what kind of completion it's offering:

```
$ print -r -- *(<Tab>
Completing glob flag
#  -- introduce glob flag
Completing glob qualifier
a  -- + access time
A  -- group-readable
c  -- + inode change time
+  -- + command name
d  -- + device
[...]
```

Which points to the [Globbing flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags) (only available when the `extendedglob` option is enabled) and [Glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) sections of the documentation.

Two different features which are both introduced by a `(`.

```
$ print -r -- *(#<Tab>
Completing glob flag
a  -- approximate matching
c  -- match repetitions of preceding pattern
e  -- match end of string
i  -- case insensitive
I  -- case sensitive matching
l  -- lower case characters match uppercase
```

In:

```
print -r -- img*(#i).jpg
```

The `(#i)` globbing flag turns case insensitive matching for the remaining of the glob pattern, the completion helps you remember what the flags are.

```
$ print -r -- *(a<Tab>
Completing time specifier
s -- seconds    h -- hours      w -- weeks
m -- minutes    d -- days       M -- Months
Completing sense [default exactly]
- -- before                             + -- since
Completing digit (days)
          August                        September
Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  Su      Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  Su
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7                   1   2   3   4
 8   9  10  11  12  13  14       5   6   7   8   9  10  11
15  16  17  18  19  20  21      12  13  14  15  16  17  18
22  23  24  25  26  27  28      19  20  21  22  23  24  25
29  30  31                      26  27  28  29  30
[...]
```

```
print -r -- *(ah-1)
```

Expands to the files last accessed less than 1 hour ago.

Note that if the `bareglobqual` option is disabled, glob qualifiers are only available using the `(#q...)` globbing flag syntax (`*.jpg(#qm-1)` for instance for the jpg files last modified within the last day).

Glob qualifiers is one of the killer features of zsh, you'll find [hundreds of answers here showing its usage](/search?q=%22glob+qualifier%22).